# How to save twitter authentication credentials for repeated use in a shiny application?

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I am new to R and Shiny

I am trying to create a simple shiny app that extracts tweets related to a search term from the twitter api. 
In R Studio,
To access twitter api for tweets, I run the following for authentication.

```
> consumer_key<-'value1'
>consumer_secret<-'value2'
> access_token<-'value3'
> access_secret<-'value4'
> setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token,access_secret)
```

Only after above four lines I can do the actual search as shown below

> tweets<-searchTwitter(search_term,n= input_number,since=start_date, until =end_date, lang= 'en')

(
i.e all the values to the variables in the searchTwitter() function are taken from the user)

Is there someway I could save the authentication credentials so that the app can always be online(running), and the credentials be loaded as and when a search is carried out.

Thanks.

Comment: What does `setup_twitter_oauth ()` return? The token? If so, you can cache that across sessions. See `?Token`  in the `httr` package

Comment: Thanks  for that .
It opens a connection to the app and verifies the auth credentials.  before setup_twitter_oauth() with httr came into use I used to do the following.


Getting a curl Certification

`library(twitteR)
library(ROAuth)
library(RCurl)`

Comment: Downloading the curl certificate and saving it.

`download.file(url="http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem",destfile="cacert.pem")

Setting up the Certification for Twitter

# Setting constant requestURL
requestURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
# Setting constant accessURL
accessURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
# Setting constant authURL
authURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
consumerKey <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
consumerSecret <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"`

Comment: #here we create the authorization object by calling function OAuthFactory




`twitCred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey,
                             consumerSecret=consumerSecret,
                             requestURL=requestURL,
                             accessURL=accessURL,
                             authURL=authURL)`


Saving and using the Certification to connect to Twitter

# Asking for access
`twitCred$handshake(cainfo="cacert.pem")`


#To enable the connection, I would direct my browser to: 
`https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=xxxx`

Comment: #When complete, I record the PIN given and provide it : xxxxxx


`registerTwitterOAuth(twitCred)`

#Saving it for future use by downloading a Cred file to the folder

**`save(list="twitCred", file="twitteR_credentials")`**

# ensure files cacert.perm and twitteR_credentials in the current working directory.

`library (twitteR)`
## Loading required package: ROAuth
## Loading required package: RCurl
## Loading required package: bitops
## Loading required package: digest
## Loading required package: rjson

`load("twitteR_credentials")`
`registerTwitterOAuth(twitCred)`

Comment: Here I am saving the credentials to a file and ensuring they can be reused .
 I want to know what changes are to be  made so that I can achieve the same from previous step,  with the current setup_twitter_oauth() way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be the best way but

```
setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key = "yourkey", consumer_secret = "yoursecret")
token <- get("oauth_token", twitteR:::oauth_cache)
token
```

Gives

```
<Token>
<oauth_endpoint>
 request:   https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token
 authorize: https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate
 access:    https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token
<oauth_app> twitter
  key:    xxxx
  secret: <hidden>
<credentials> oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, user_id, screen_name, x_auth_expires
---
```

Then cache it

```
token$cache()
```

Comment: Hi Scott. I was able to save them as you suggested. how do i actually load them(credentials) for R to use them. 
In addition to your answer, 
I did the following

`token$cache()`
`save(token,file="oauth_cache.RData")`
`'load("oauth_cache.Rdata")`


`.onLoad<-function(libname,pkgname){ 
cachedToken<-new.env()
dataFile <- system.file("data/oauth_cache.RData", package="packageName")
load(dataFile, cachedToken)
assign("oauth_token", cachedToken$local_cache, envir=twitteR:::oauth_cache)
rm(cachedToken)
}`

Comment: Yes, no errors turned up , so I think saving the authentication credentials in the way you suggested worked.

 How should I load them/call these saved credentials in my shiny app so that I can query the  twitter api for tweets

Comment: I don't know the particulars of Shiny very well, but i imagine you can just load the cached file with readRDS or load maybe, then `assign()`, as you have done